# Android pass value to Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have to pass a value in the sqlite db spinner of another activity.
the value of the step as follows:

```
extras.putString ("category", tv4.getText().toString ());
```

But then as I insert it in the spinner?

```
spinner.set ...... (i.getStringExtra("category"));
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please post more complete sample code, and any logcat errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your spinner has an adapter and an array that fills that adapter.  You need to first find the index of the string you are passing in from the array.  Then you will set the spinner's position to that index.

Comment: is in fact ill my spinner has:
`ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

  
   dataAdapter
     .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Comment: I do not know how to do